# accessing Doubleclick Campaign Manager data through Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, double-click-advertising

I am attempting to bring Doubleclick Campaign Manager dimensions through the GA API and am getting the following error message - 
"Restricted dimension(s): *(DCM dimensions I entered in the query string)* can only be queried under certain conditions. For details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.

There is no guidance on that referencing site. Has anyone run into and solved this - or is it an auth restriction (shouldn't be: I have admin rights to the property).
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your property is not Google Analytics 360 you cannot query any of the metrics of the DCM. Take a look again [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=doubleclick_campaign_manager) beside each metrics explanation there is the (Analytics 360 only). That is the only thing I can think if you also have admin rights on the property. Also check if you are authenticated with the correct account in any API or Query Explorer you are using

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed GA 360 that I'm using and to which I have admin rights. I will check on autho for API but believe that my level of permission across the board is the same - API, interface, etc.